# hide placeholder with css

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a responsive theme. And I'm facing the input form problem here. In the desktop view, the input will not have placeholder but have label.

However, when it comes to the mobile view, I will hide this input label and change this label with placeholder.

```
<input name="name" type="text" placehoder="insert your name">
```

How can one hide this placeholder with CSS?

Comment: because CSS can not manipulate the attribute of a HTML tag.  CSS can provide the style. you can do with JavaScript/Jquery

Comment: if using css, no way to do this

Comment: but you can try one thing.. set the placeholder color as your background color so it will look like you dont have placeholder..

Comment: thanks everyone. all solution bellow is working like charm!

Answer (score 80):

This will hide the placeholder only for desktops (and large tablets):

```css
@media (min-width:1025px) and (min-width:1281px) {
     ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        /* WebKit browsers */
         color: transparent;
    }
     :-moz-placeholder {
        /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
         color: transparent;
    }
     ::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
         color: transparent;
    }
     :-ms-input-placeholder {
        /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
         color: transparent;
    }
     input::placeholder {
         color: transparent;
    }
     textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        /* WebKit browsers */
         color: transparent;
    }
     textarea:-moz-placeholder {
        /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
         color: transparent;
    }
     textarea::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
         color: transparent;
    }
     textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
        /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
         color: transparent;
    }
     textarea::placeholder {
         color: transparent;
    }
}
```

[Check it on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNmYNP).

Comment: how to do this with the textarea,!

Comment: Edited my answer to include textarea. Try it and let me know.

Comment: and latest chrome.

Comment: Instead of using `color: transparent`, simply use `opacity: 0` to make it work in latest browsers.

Comment: Folks, actually what did not work was the Stackoverflow snippet. I have removed it and replaced it with a Codepen link.

Comment: additionally u can add user-select: none; for making the placeholder not been able to be selected if u do ctrl+A command

Answer (score 27):

CSS only provides the styling, it can not remove the actual placeholder.

What you can do it, set the placeholder text color as your background color of textbox, so it will look like you don't have placeholder..

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #fff;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #fff;
    opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #fff;
    opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #fff;
}
```

Check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0dcvs7s/)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean in the first sentence, please? I don't quite understand the statement.

Comment: @Henders.. ;) hahah it was just typo,  I wanted to say css provides only styling

Comment: If your browser supports styling the placeholder, it also supports `rgba(255,255,255,0)`. Your solution only works for white inputs.

Comment: Am I missing why you can't use `display: none;`, `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;`?

Comment: @Edmund, he asked to hide the placeholder text. Not txtbox itself. If you will use display, opacity or visibility it will hide txtbox itself. But requirements was to hide just placeholder text inside txtbox. Hope it make sense.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, targeting `:placeholder` in CSS target's the placeholder pseudo element, which IS the text, not the text box, so setting display/opacity/visiblity will affect the placeholder (text) only. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Edmund, it might be the another solution if you find its working as expected, you can post you answer here as well.

Comment: Just for clarification, if you still have to support IE11, setting the visibility, display, color or opacity of the placeholder, will unexpectedly change the style of the input, too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use media queries and hide and show based on required resolution:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
      ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         color: lightgray !important; 
      }
      :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         color: lightgray !important;  
      }

      ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         color: lightgray !important;  
      }

      :-ms-input-placeholder {  
         color: lightgray !important;  
      }
      #labelID
      {
         display:none !important;
      }
}
```

**Normal Styles**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         color: transparent;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
         color: transparent;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
         color: transparent;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
         color: transparent;
}

#labelID{
        display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use JS

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 600){  
        $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
    }   
});
```

Comment: `removeAttr` is not hiding, when user restores the image back to the original size the text inside the input field wont be there

Comment: With this approach, we can't then use input:not(:placeholder-shown) to style an adjacent label based upon text being within the input (e.g., to place the label overlapping the input or not overlapping).

Answer (score 4):

Make both the input field and placeholder text same color. There is no other way with css.

```
@media all and (max-width:736px){
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:white;
    }

    :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color:white;
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color:white;
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color:white;
    }   
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="id_here" placeholder="Your Label">
```

Make the placeholder hide in desktop view

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
 }
```

OR

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
   color:white;
}
```

1. Change input(or textarea whatever) to #id_here or class name, if you dont want to change all inputs in the website
2. Use for different browsers

   -webkit-input-placeholder
   -ms-input-placeholder
   -moz-placeholder

Answer (score 3):

This Code/css shows the 'placeholder' only on focus:

```
:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit browsers */
    color: transparent;
}
:not(:focus):-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: transparent;
}
:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: transparent;
}
:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: transparent;
}
```