# Show/Hide placeholder text

Tags: jquery, css, placeholder

I have several textboxes with placeholders described for example:

```
<input class="form-control" id="txtAddress" placeholder="Address" type="text">
<input class="form-control" id="txtZip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text">
```

I want to hide these placeholders when I call the `SetErrorStateForControl` function.

```
var SetErrorStateForControl = function (elemObj, msg) 
{
    $('<span class="reqDiv" name="Required">' + msg + '</span>').prependTo(elemObj.closest('div'));
    //hide placeholders of all textboxes
}
```

and on focus I want to put the placeholders back.

```
$("#Offer_Form").find(".form-control").on("focus", function (e) {
        //Show placeholders back
    });
```

Is it even possible to hide and show placeholders with jquery OR css?

Comment: provide complete code

Comment: @AnkurBhadania complete code as in? I have no idea how to hide and show placeholders so I have added comments for that

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794947/hide-placeholder-with-css

Comment: you can use add or remove attr() for adding and removing placeholders and it will do your job here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this .

It might helps you to understand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Place Holder</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=Offer_Form>
            <input class="form-control MyClass" id="txtAddress" placeholder="Address" type="text">
            <input class="form-control MyClass" id="txtZip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text">    
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).on("focus" , ".MyClass" , function () {

            $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');

        });

        $(document).on("focusout" , ".MyClass" , function () {

            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this).attr('placeholder' , "My PlaceHolder");
            }

        });

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about adding attribute? Do I need to write the code for adding them back once or for each textbox?

Comment: edited the ans,.  now the thing is somehow you have to idetify that user has focused out from  address element or zipcode element. so that you can add the place holder accordingly.

Comment: Why you are giving 2 answer?? if first one is not good then edit and merge the other answer in that. Please merge and help in making clean and spamless site. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

#### HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Text" id="txt1" />
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('#txt1').focus(function(){
  $(this).attr('placeholder','');
});
$('#txt1').focusout(function(){
  $(this).attr('placeholder','Enter Text');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$("input").each(
            function(){
                $(this).data('holder',$(this).attr('placeholder'));
                $(this).focusin(function(){
                    $(this).attr('placeholder','');
                });
                $(this).focusout(function(){
                    $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('holder'));
                });
                
        });
```

```css
li{padding:15px;list-style-type: none;}
input{padding:8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <ul class="field-set field-set-stacked">
       <li class="field field-text">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
       </li>
       <li class="field">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
       </li>
       <li class="field">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter amount" />
       </li>
    </ul>                  
</form>
```