# Removing what's inside a label with CSS

Tags: html, css

Can I remove the word Search coming from a file bootstrap with css?
Here my code:

```
<div id="items-data-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>
    Search:
    <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="items-data-table"></label></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide placeholder with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794947/hide-placeholder-with-css)

Comment: No, I've added a placeholder in order to remove the word Search

Comment: Is there a reason you can't edit the HTML?

Comment: Yess, this word "Search" comes from a bootstrap file, in my html code it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't remove the text at all, then you could use a combination of `text-indent` and `line-height` to hide the text and remove its effect on the layout.

This works by shifting the text off-screen using a negative `text-indent` and reducing the `line-height` to 0 to prevent it from pushing the input down.

The input can then be reset by setting it to `display: block;` to prevent indentation affecting it.

```css
.dataTables_filter {
  text-indent: -1000vw;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Reset layout for the input */
.dataTables_filter input {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="items-data-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>
  Search:
  <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="items-data-table"></label>
</div>
```